# Calling a function using the context pointer using JNI on android causes a segfault

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, google-project-tango

I found this bit of code in one of the [example tango projects](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c/blob/master/rgb-depth-sync-example/app/src/main/jni/rgb_depth_sync_application.cc#L27) using the JNI and I have no idea what the context is nor how to use it. The example code works, but my code does not.

```
void OnXYZijAvailableRouter(void *context, const TangoXYZij *xyz_ij) {
    SynchronizationApplication *app =
        static_cast<SynchronizationApplication *>(context);
    app->OnXYZijAvailable(xyz_ij);
}
```

I tried mimicking it below:

```
void OnFrameAvailableRouter(void *context, const TangoCameraId id,
                            const TangoImageBuffer *buffer) {
    SynchronizationApplication *app =
        static_cast<SynchronizationApplication *>(context);
    LOGE("Before onframe call.");
    app->onFrameAvailable(id, buffer);
    LOGE("After onframe call.");
}
```

When I try to run it, however, I get this output:

```
Before onframe call.
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000308 (code=1), thread 15673 (Binder_2)
```

Now I managed to find the pointer that causes the seg fault, but I have no idea why it does not work.

Naturally, I might have done something wrong, but I have no idea what since I made an exact copy of the code in the example.

```
int SynchronizationApplication::TangoConnectCallbacks() {
    TangoErrorType depth_ret =
            TangoService_connectOnXYZijAvailable(OnXYZijAvailableRouter);

    depth_ret = TangoService_connectOnFrameAvailable(TangoCameraId::TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR, NULL,
                                         OnFrameAvailableRouter);

    return depth_ret;
}
```

The functions I call from the routers.

```
void OnXYZijAvailable(const TangoXYZij *xyz_ij);
void onFrameAvailable(const TangoCameraId id, const TangoImageBuffer *buffer);
```

What exactly is the context? I have read some explanations, but I still do not understand why I can call the function using the context in the example above, nor why I need the router function at all. I have read [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android) and [the android page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) on the concept, but I see no link between the context and my class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `OnXYZijAvailableRouter` (the depth callback), the context is the instance passed in from the `TangoService_connect` function. I believe in the application class, there should be a line like this: `TangoService_connect(this, tango_config_);` So `this` become the context when the callback is called. This context also applies to pose and event callbacks.

In the case of `OnFrameAvailableRouter`, the context is the instance you passed in in the `TangoService_connectOnFrameAvailable`. In this case, the code is setting a NULL as context, but in the callback, it's trying the call a function on NULL. That's the crash point.

I believe if you change the it to `TangoService_connectOnFrameAvailable(TangoCameraId::TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR, this, OnFrameAvailableRouter);` it should work fine.

The router function is for the callbacks, I haven't find a way of giving a function pointer of a instance to the API. But let me know if you find a way to do that, I would like to know as well..

Comment: Indeed, that is what did it. Thanks. I tried and failed to give it a function pointer of the class itself, but if I manage to do it I will comment here.